# How to format thousands separator when exporting from r to excel using xlsx package?

Tags: r, formatting, xlsx

I am exporting some dataframes from r to excel using the `xlsx` and `rJava` packages, which works well. However, I want the numbers in excel to be separated by thousands using dots, i.e. `1.000.000,00`. Can anybody provide some example code to achieve this?

Comment: You can specify the separators in Excel.  Under Options -> Advanced: Unclick "Use system separators" and specify your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

```
library(xlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows  <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex=1)
cell.1 <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1)[[1,1]]
setCellValue(cell.1, 1234567.89)

cs = CellStyle(wb) +
    DataFormat("#,##0.00")
setCellStyle(cell.1, cs)
saveWorkbook(wb, 'EuroFormatNumbers.xlsx')
```

[image: EuroFormat numbers]

Comment: How would I incorporate this into the ```addDataFrame``` function of the ```xlsx``` package? Setting ```colStyle = cs``` does not work unfortunately. I can only set the columns manually to this format using ```colStyle = list(`1`=cs, `2`=cs)``` and so on. How can I format the whole DataFrame this way?